# best algorithm to delete records from database?

Tags: php, mysql

Folks,

There are 2500 records in master table city which has references in approx. 22 another tables as city ID or city name.

Now i will have to delete 2000 records from city master table and cross check in another 22 tables where city ID exists and if references exist then modify the ID.

I made a simple script in PHP but it took 15-16 hours and i cannot do same on production server.  All 22 tables have on average 700,000 to 800,000 rows.

Please provide best possible solution.

Thanks

Comment: 2000 records, 15 hours. You're doing something wrong.

Comment: 15 hours. I think that's amazing. I couldn't get my scripts to run that long if I tried.

Comment: By 7-8 Lakhs rows, you mean 700,000 to 800,000 rows, right?

Comment: If you have FK constraints you just delete from main table and poof everything should be gone in like 10 seconds for 2k records. I'm pretty sure my while(true) loops run faster than 15 hours.

Comment: @Jesus, he's saying he needs to replace FK's with new valid ID, rather than cascade delete

Comment: Ravi - you're only going to get real help if you post the script for us to see

Comment: People wondering about the 15 hour time quoted: As I understand it (translation issues aside), there are 2000 records in the "master" table that need to be deleted, but for *each* of the other 22 tables, there are hundreds of thousands of rows that reference the deleted records and themselves need to be deleted or edited. So we're talking about working with millions of rows in total, not 2000.

Comment: yup ... right ...i will have cross check all references in 22 tables where on average each table has  700,000 to 800,000 rows

Comment: @zerkms pls see John's comments .. seems there is gap in understanding  problem

Comment: @RaviRaj: there is a gap in explanation, not in understanding. There is a big difference

Comment: @RaviRaj: without any details I propose the **universal** solution (yes, it works in any case) - tune your queries and database schema.

Comment: @John Flatness: people just followed **his** question. He said he has an issue with **deletion from a table with 2000 rows**. No one forced him on emphasizing on *meaningless information*. The better question - the better answer. See, even after referencing him to a lack of information he did not provide anything that could help to answer more precisely. Enough said.

Comment: @zerkms Hope now you got issue! .. actually i am looking for best algorithm to handle this. explaining again. "there are 2000 records in the "master" table that need to be deleted, but for each of the other 22 tables, there are hundreds of thousands of rows that reference the deleted records and themselves need to be deleted or edited"

Comment: @RaviRaj: there is still no details - **optimize your queries**.

Comment: @zerkms Perhaps I shouldn't have directed my comment at "people wondering," but my intent was to try and help *provide* or at least confirm some of the missing or unclear information, not to scold people.

Comment: @John Flatness: that's ok, but the much OP sees "strange" answers - the sooner he gets that the question should contain **enough information** to answer it.

Comment: @All: found 2 links .. which are little bit relate to my problem ..

Comment: @All: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1436749/delete-records-from-table-using-another-table) & [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3970143/php-mysql-how-to-delete-a-users-records-from-two-tables)

Comment: Are you the DBA by yourself? Do you index your tables with PK, FK and/or UK columns? Do you write your queries with the WHERE on an indexed column? Not doing so will make the queries to take ages.

Comment: You say 'modify the ID' in the referencing tables...does that mean that you have a table mapping old city ID values to new ones?  What about the tables that don't use a city ID but use a city name instead?  Do you have to map the old name to a new name?  How are you identifying the 2000 cities to be deleted?  Is it fair to suppose that the 2000 cities to be deleted are various misspellings and alternative spellings for the 500 cities to be retained?  So, although you are deleting 80% of the cities, they do not constitute 80% of the references in the other 22 tables?

Comment: @Jonathan:I have that's data in excel format. in that excel i have mapping old city id with new city id. that excel is provided by product & sales team.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, this is a shot in the dark, but here goes:

Remove the cities one at a time. So for each city, update all the other 22 massive tables. This will be slower overall, but will execute in smaller chunks (1/2500th of 16 hours ~= 20-25 seconds). Once the tables are updated, remove that row from the master city table. Rinse and repeat ~2500 times.

Comment: Since 1/2500th of an hour is about 1.5 seconds, that's about 20-25 seconds per city, isn't it?  I agree with the method you suggest, though; I was debating whether to suggest it.  One advantage of this is that it can be scheduled over many days, if need so be - a hundred cities here, a hundred cities there - without taking everything out of commission while it is happening.

Answer (score 0):

> I made a simple script in PHP but it took 15-16 hours and i cannot do same on production server

If it's simple then why not post it here? Without knowing your algorithm and data schema we can't guess what the best algorithm would be.

Certainly you should already have ensured that you're using appropriate indexes for your queries and that the mysql instance is tuned (you should probably be configuring more sort_buffer, repair_threads, thread_cache and max_sort_file_size than the default).

In general bulk operations will be much faster done in SQL rather than PHP. And its probably a lot simpler to change the foreign key references before you delete the master record (not to monetion you're not breaking your data integrity during the process).